# K8 Certificate Authority for Web Applications in Private Domain

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm looking for a CA solution that I can use w/ the webapps running in my private domain.  I'm using nginx ingress controller to route to different applications based on path, and I'm using self signed certs to secure the apps w/ https.  I want to start using a CA, something that I can run directly on the cluster, that'll handle the signing so that I don't have to distribute the certs manually.  Any ideas? What's the goto solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple solutions for this, but one is the cert-manager:

https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager

You can install it and create a CA issuer with your CA. Then you can create certificates using k8s yaml manifests, and the cert-manager takes care of creating the secrets.